# IF Statement Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

```
strTemp = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BreakCon").PivotFields("Service Type").PivotItems("International Data")
        If Err = 0 Then FieldExists = True Else FieldExists = False
        If FieldExists = True Then
          With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BreakCon").PivotFields("Service Type")
            .PivotItems("International Data").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("Non Contracted").Visible = False
        ElseIf FieldExists = False Then
         With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BreakCon").PivotFields("Service Type")
            .PivotItems("Non Contracted").Visible = False

        Else
            MsgBox ("Error")
        End If
```

Occasionally the data passing through the code has "International Data" however occasionally it doesn't so i added this If statement to try and check whether "International Data" is in the Pivot Table and if not then go to the next if statement. Can anyone see an issue with this code? i have tried all of the ways i know but have hit a brickwall! Cheers!

Comment: Which line causes an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this (AFAIK) is to loop through the pivot items in the pivot field and check for the existence of the desired item.

I also assume that in your above code, you may be using On Error Resume Next to brute force you're way through the issue, but the method below as the advantage of using built VBA functionality to smoothly handle the issue.

See below:

```
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pf as PivotField
Dim pi as PivotItem

Set pt = Worksheet("mySheet").PivotTables("BreakCon")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Service Type")

For each pi in pf.PivotItems

    If pi.Name = "International Data" Then 
        pf.PivotItems("International Data").Visible = False
        Exit For
    End If

Next

pf.PivotItems("Non Contracted").Visible = False
```

Comment: Cheers for that Scott, yeah i had used a temporary way to get around the issue whilst i ran it the first time but that code you gave works great!